# Connecting UITableView Cells to separate View Controllers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have multiple separate View Controllers (which I need to have), and want to connect each row in the TableView to a separate View Controller.

As for code, this is what I have so far. I've only made the tableView:

My **ViewController.h**

```
[...]
@interface SimpleTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
[...]
```

My **ViewController.m**

```
[...]
@implementation SimpleTableViewController
{
NSArray *tableData;
}

[...]

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
}

[...]

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [tableData count];
}

[...]

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

I've also connected the tableView to the dataSource and delegate. What I need is to have each one of those entries above (one, two, three) connect to separate view controllers. I've already made all the view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need if-else or switch statements in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        ViewController1 *vc1 = "instantiate a controller here"
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        ViewController2 *vc2 = "instantiate a controller here"
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
    etc......
```

Answer (score 0):

Each row in the table view controller is a UITableViewCell, so I'm guessing that's what you are referring to when you want to have control over each row's 'view controller'.

You need to subclass UITableViewCell and then you can create a new instance of that subclass when you come to use the cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

EDIT: Granted you dont HAVE to subclass the UITableViewCell, but if you want complete control over it then you do.